# How do I enable the drive labels in Directory Opus 11?

Tags: directoryopus

I have just bought a copy of Directory Opus 11, which is without a doubt one of the best applications for Windows. I am struggling though how I can show the drive (HDD) labels in the dedicated panel? The current function I have for the button is:

```
Go DRIVEBUTTONS=fixed
```

and I have "Show Label" enabled in the same window but I only see the drive letter and not its name. I want it to look something like this:

```
C: Local Disk
```

What command do I have to add to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to append `labels` as a function like so:

```
Go DRIVEBUTTONS=fixed,labels
```